# Custom deserialization of List using Jackson, SpringBoot - not working

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, deserialization

I am trying to make custom deserialization of List. I have followed a few tips online that I could find but couldn't make it work.

**Car.class**

```
public class Car {

    private String market;
    private String date;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDeserializer.class)
    private List<CarValue> cars;
```

**CustomDeserializer.java**

```
public class CustomDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<CarValue>> {

    @Override
    public List<CarValue> deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        JsonNode node = p.getCodec().readTree(p);
        List<CarValue> result = new ArrayList<CarValue>();
        for(JsonNode value : node) {
            //result.add(node.get("name"));
        }

        return result;
    }

}
```

I am not sure how to return wanted data from my `CustomDeserializer` class.

From `List<QuoteValue>` I only want to return data with key `name`.

How can I do that?

Comment: `@JsonExclude`?

Comment: Tried @JsonIgnore and still there I think I need to parse it in my model but I don't know how :/

Comment: There should be an ObjectMapper bean already, no need to instantiate it https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.x/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-json Then just use whatever features of Gson, or Jackson, or JSON-B depending on which one is configured in your case.

Comment: @Aivaras I am using Jackson and I have ObjectMaper created in my `Loader.java` class. But I have to do parsing in my `CarValue.class`. So how can I get data from ObjectMapper in one class to another?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of what I have.

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;

import java.util.List;

public class VoucherPartnerGiftCardOp {
  @Expose
  private int voucherPartnerGiftCardID;
  @Expose
  private int marchantID;


  public VoucherPartnerGiftCardOp() {
  }

  public int getVoucherPartnerGiftCardID() {
    return voucherPartnerGiftCardID;
  }

  public void setVoucherPartnerGiftCardID(int voucherPartnerGiftCardID) {
    this.voucherPartnerGiftCardID = voucherPartnerGiftCardID;
  }

  public int getMarchantID() {
    return marchantID;
  }

....

  public String toJson() {
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().setPrettyPrinting().create();
    return gson.toJson(this);
  }
}
```

Comment: OP mentioned the usage of Jackson